# Pass certain touches through UIScrollView to underlying views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've got a view that has two subviews:

1. Subview A, a UIView (contains other views, which contain UIButtons, views with gesturerecognizer ...)
2. Subview B, a UIScrollView (contains some views, but has transparent regions).

The scrollview is on top of Subview A and has the full device width/height. I want the user to be able to interact - through the transparent regions - with all those buttons and gesture reconizers below the scrollview, while still being able to scroll (so passing on the hittest is out).

Seems like an easy enough task, but I can't get it to work. The scrollview is always blocking all touches.

Any idea how I would accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: Why is the scroll view over the other view in the first place ?

Comment: The views in the scrollview need to overlap the views underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've somewhat solved this now by adding the view that's supposed to be below the scrollview to the scrollview as the first subview, and shifting its position in scrollViewDidScroll:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self updateBottomViewPosition];
}

- (void)updateBottomViewPosition {
    CGPoint contentOffset = _mainScrollView.contentOffset;

    CGFloat y = MAX(contentOffset.y, 0);

    CGRect frame = _bottomPage.frame;
    if (y != frame.origin.y) {
        frame.origin.y = y;
        _leadPage.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

This works, but it's probably not as elegant as possible.

Comment: Just the solution I was looking for. It's a shame IOS doesn't offer an easier way. Still, this is cleaner than implementing the tap gestures.

Answer (score 16):

You should subclass the UIScrollView and overwrite the following method:

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

If this method returns NO the scrollview will be "transparent" for touch events.

As you want the scrollview to be "transparent" for touch events only if the touch is in a transparent area of your scrollview, your implementation should look like:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     return ![self isPointInsideATransparentRegion:point]; //you need to implement isPointInsideATransparentRegion to check whether the point touched is in a transparent region or not
}
```

Comment: This would work if the user should only scroll on the solid areas. However a pan gesture on the transparent area should still make the scrollview scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Based in René's answer, this works if the background view is fixed (f.e. at the top of the view) and the bottom scroll has bounce.

```
#pragma mark - Scroll delegate

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self updateBottomViewPosition];
}

- (void)updateBottomViewPosition {
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;

    CGFloat y = MAX(contentOffset.y, 0);


    CGRect frame = self.fixedView.frame;
    if (y > 0) {
        frame.origin.y = y;
    } else {
        frame.origin.y = 0;
    }
    self.fixedView.frame = frame;
}
```

You can use this to create also a nice paralax effect, if you don't want it to be fixed you should change the y value to your wanted transition movement.